# How to return custom error if validation failed with Gin

Tags: go, go-gin

For example I've got the following `struct`

```
type Address struct {
    City string `json:"city" binding:"required"`
    AddressLine string `json:"address_line" binding:"required"`
}
```

and I've got the following function to handle request from users

```
func AddressCreate(c *gin.Context) {
    var address Address
    if err := c.BindJSON(&address); err == nil {
        // if everything is good save to database
        // and return success message
        db.Create(&address)
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H {"status":"success"})
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
    }
}
```

Expected behavior is to return JSON, formatted this way

```
[
     {
         "city":"required"
     }
     {
         "address_line":"required"
     }
]
```

But I'm getting an error formatted like this

```
"Address.City": {
    "FieldNamespace": "Address.City",
    "NameNamespace": "City",
    "Field": "City",
    "Name": "City",
    "Tag": "required",
    "ActualTag": "required",
    "Kind": 24,
    "Type": {},
    "Param": "",
    "Value": ""
},
"Address.AddressLine": {
    "FieldNamespace": "AddressLine",
    "NameNamespace": "AddressLine",
    "Field": "AddressLine",
    "Name": "AddressLine",
    "Tag": "required",
    "ActualTag": "required",
    "Kind": 24,
    "Type": {},
    "Param": "",
    "Value": ""
}
```

What I tried:
I created function which casts `error` to `ValidationErrors` and iterates through all `FieldError`'s in it

```
func ListOfErrors(e error) []map[string]string {
    ve := e.(validator.ValidationErrors)
    InvalidFields := make([]map[string]string, 0)

    for _, e := range ve {
        errors := map[string]string{}
        // field := reflect.TypeOf(e.NameNamespace)
        errors[e.Name] = e.Tag
        InvalidFields = append(InvalidFields, errors)
    }

    return InvalidFields
}
```

The output look's much better

```
[
    {
        "City":"required"
    },
    {
        "AddressLine":"required"
    }
]
```

But I cannot solve the problem with the name of the fields. I cannot swap `Name` into `name` which I noted in structs tag `json:"city"`. So my question is did I choose correct way to solve the problem if the answer is yes how to get structs JSON tag for field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return custom error message from struct tag validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70069834/return-custom-error-message-from-struct-tag-validation) (dupe with latest versions of Gin and Go, and without `reflect`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be same as defined in your json tag, then you should use reflection to pull that tag from your data type.

I don't have your libraries, so can't compile and check it. But I believe what you are after should go along those lines:

```
func ListOfErrors(address *Address, e error) []map[string]string {
    ve := e.(validator.ValidationErrors)
    InvalidFields := make([]map[string]string, 0)

    for _, e := range ve {
        errors := map[string]string{}
        // field := reflect.TypeOf(e.NameNamespace)
        field, _ := reflect.TypeOf(address).Elem().FieldByName(e.Name)
        jsonTag := string(field.Tag.Get("json"))
        errors[jsonTag] = e.Tag
        InvalidFields = append(InvalidFields, errors)
    }

    return InvalidFields
}
```

Note that it is a bit contrived as type of `address` parameter is essentially known. So, not strictly required as a function parameter. But you can change `address *Address` to `address interface{}` and use it for other types too.

Disclaimer: I skipped error checking for brevity, but you certainly should check for errors in your code (e.g. no such field error or no json tag on that field).

Comment: Thank you for response. Is it possible to not pass `Address` as parameter? I want to create a solution for all types not only for `Address`.

Comment: That's what the Note was about. If you change type of `address` parameter to `interface{}` you can use it with any type, not just Address and it will work. But you still need to pass the object you were validating. Go is statically typed language, so you need an object to get it's type. But I don't know of any API that will give you type by type name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToSnake` to snake case the names:

```
import (
    "unicode"
)

// ToSnake convert the given string to snake case following the Golang format:
// acronyms are converted to lower-case and preceded by an underscore.
func ToSnake(in string) string {
    runes := []rune(in)
    length := len(runes)

    var out []rune
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        if i > 0 && unicode.IsUpper(runes[i]) && ((i+1 < length && unicode.IsLower(runes[i+1])) || unicode.IsLower(runes[i-1])) {
            out = append(out, '_')
        }
        out = append(out, unicode.ToLower(runes[i]))
    }

    return string(out)
}



func ListOfErrors(e error) []map[string]string {
    ve := e.(validator.ValidationErrors)
    invalidFields := make([]map[string]string, 0)

    for _, e := range ve {
        errors := map[string]string{}
        errors[ToSnake(e.Name)] = e.Tag
        invalidFields = append(InvalidFields, errors)
    }

    return invalidFields
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response but `ToLower` won't work in second case when field name is `AddressLine` because I'm expecting `address_line`

Comment: updated the answer. you can use third-party libraries too.
https://github.com/iancoleman/strcase