# Return custom error message from struct tag validation

Tags: validation, go, go-gin

I'm using Go 1.17 with Gin and I want to implement a struct validation before sending the data to my database. I took the example from [Gin documentation](https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/custom-validators/).

In the struct we can declare different tags to validate a field like this:

```
type User struct {
    FirstName      string `json:"first_name" binding:"required"`
    LastName       string `json:"last_name" binding:"required"`
    Age            uint8  `json:"age" binding:"gte=0,lte=130"`
    Email          string `json:"email" binding:"required,email"`
    FavouriteColor string `json:"favourite_color" binding:"iscolor"`
}
```

And in the handler I can grab the error like this:

```
var u User
if err := c.ShouldBindWith(&u, binding.Query); err == nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "Good Job"})
} else {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
}
```

The error message will be:

```
{
    "error": "Key: 'User.FirstName' Error:Field validation for 'FirstName' failed on the 'required' tag\nKey: 'User.LastName' Error:Field validation for 'LastName' failed on the 'required' tag\nKey: 'User.Email' Error:Field validation for 'Email' failed on the 'required' tag\nKey: 'User.FavouriteColor' Error:Field validation for 'FavouriteColor' failed on the 'iscolor' tag"
}
```

The error messages are too verbose how it's possible to returns a better error to the user? I'd like to model the json response like:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "first_name": "This field is required",
        "last_name": "This field is required",
        "age": "This field is required",
        "email": "Invalid email"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gin gonic uses the package `github.com/go-playground/validator/v10` to perform binding validation. If the validation fails, the error returned is a [`validator.ValidationErrors`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator#ValidationErrors).

This is not mentioned explicitly but here in [Model binding and validation](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#model-binding-and-validation) it states:

> Gin uses go-playground/validator/v10 for validation. Check the full docs on tags usage here.

That links to the `go-playground/validator/v10` documentation, where you find the paragraph [Validation Functions Return Type error](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator?utm_source=godoc#hdr-Validation_Functions_Return_Type_error).

You can use the standard `errors` package to check if the error is that, unwrap it, and access the single fields, which are [`validator.FieldError`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator#FieldError). From that, you can construct whatever error message you want.

Given an error model like this:

```
type ApiError struct {
    Field string
    Msg   string
}
```

You can do this:

```
    var u User
    err := c.BindQuery(&u);
    if err != nil {
        var ve validator.ValidationErrors
        if errors.As(err, &ve) {
            out := make([]ApiError, len(ve))
            for i, fe := range ve {
                out[i] = ApiError{fe.Field(), msgForTag(fe.Tag())}
            }
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"errors": out})
        }
        return
    }
```

with a helper function to output a custom error message for your validation rules:

```
func msgForTag(tag string) string {
    switch tag {
    case "required":
        return "This field is required"
    case "email":
        return "Invalid email"
    }
    return ""
}
```

In my test, this outputs:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "Field": "Number",
            "Msg": "This field is required"
        }
    ]
}
```

PS: To have a json output with dynamic keys, you can use `map[string]string` instead of a fixed struct model.

Comment: There is a way to get the json struct tag name in the field value ? E.g as you can see in the `FirstName` field I named my json tag `first_name`. I checked the doc https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#FieldError and the `fe.Field()` method should work but actually I have the same behavior as `fe.StructField()` I don't know why

Comment: @John to have different returns, use [`RegisterTagNameFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator#Validate.RegisterTagNameFunc)

Comment: Here is an example of how to use RegisterTagNameFunc to get the tag name: https://github.com/go-playground/validator/issues/337#issuecomment-1716859865